# lxml memory leakage with Python3 in Ubuntu12.04

Tags: python, memory, lxml

I just installed `lxml` using `easy_install` in a Ubuntu12.04 pc, with Python 3.2.3 installed. 
`lxml` is the latest version 3.0Alpha.

I tried the following code:

```
import lxml.html

def proc_tweet(ss):
    html=lxml.html.fragment_fromstring(ss)
    ps=html.xpath("//p[@node-type='feed_list_content']")

def test():
    ss=''
    f=open('test')
    for l in f: ss+=l.strip()
    f.close()
    while True: proc_tweet(ss)

if __name__=='__main__':
    test()
```

Here, 'test' is a file, includes a short HTML fragment:

```
<dl action-type="feed_list_item" mid="3409553360609821" class="feed_list W_linecolor"> 
    <dd class="content"> 
        <p node-type="feed_list_content">This is a drill.</p> 
    </dd> 
    <dd class="clear"></dd> 
</dl>
```

The issue is `lxml` eats all my memory as time goes by. I tried this

```
del ps
del html
```

It doesn't work. Anyone knows why?

Comment: How did you measure *"eats all my memory"*? Operating systems allocate memory to programs as requested, but won't reclaim the memory unless needed elsewhere even if the program has freed that memory again, so that *could* be the case here.

Comment: When I commented ps=html.xpath("//p[@node-type='feed_list_content']")
this line. The memory usage is OK.

Comment: I mean it will use out the 8G memory at last. Python manages memory usage automatically. It should auto free memory. But it doesn't in my code.

Comment: Seeing as this is an alpha release, there could very well be a leak. Have you reported this to the lxml project? They'll be much better set up to diagnose this. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I sent them emails. NO response.

Comment: There is an [issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/issues); file an issue there.

Comment: Sorry, there is *also* a [tracker on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml); I believe 3 alpha bugs should be filed there instead.

Comment: I finally confirmed it is a bug of lxml 3.0Alpha2. Because when I tried the old version lxml 2.3.5. There isn't that problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that was fixed in 3.0 beta 1.

For future reference, it is always best to report a problem with a software tool directly to the project that maintains it rather than just posting it at an arbitrary place on the Internet. The launchpad bug tracker is the right place to report lxml bugs. The github tracker is mostly just used for pull requests.